# PHP - How to make use of auto-complete

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

Suppose I have some glue-code DB in **PHP** that loads a DB-row into a standard class.

```
class TestObject
{
    public $id; 
    public $name;   
}
```

I have a function that updates the DB so it expects to receive such a class:

```
function updateEntry($testObjectData)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Is there some way to hint to Eclipse that this class is in fact an instance of "TestObject" and not some generic object thus make use of auto complete ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: did you try to use typehinting? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 4):

```
function updateEntry(TestObject $testObjectData)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out:
Instead of:

```
function updateEntry($testObjectData)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Do:

```
function updateEntry(TestObject $testObjectData)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php